# Unable to connect to GKE cluster from GitHub actions due to net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, kubectl

I have a workflow that authenticates to a GKE cluster and attempts to do a `kubectl get pods`

```yaml
     - name: set up gcloud
        uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'
        with:
          version: '>= 363.0.0'
          install_components: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin

      - name: get cluster credentials
        id: get-credentials
        uses: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials@v1
        with:
          cluster_name: "${{ steps.cluster-name.outputs.CLUSTER_NAME }}"
          location: "${{ steps.cluster-zone.outputs.CLUSTER_ZONE }}"

      - name: install kubectl
        uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v3
        with:
            version: "v${{ steps.k8s-master-version.outputs.MASTER_VERSION}}"
      
      - name: get pods
        shell: bash
        run: |
          unset http_proxy
          unset https_proxy
          kubectl -v 10 get pods
```

All steps succeed, except the last one. Fails as follows

```
I0606 18:58:03.301800    3690 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:11.22.33.44:443 succeed
I0606 18:58:13.302381    3690 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://11.22.33.44/api?timeout=32s  in 10001 milliseconds
I0606 18:58:13.302406    3690 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 1 ms TLSHandshake 10000 ms Duration 10001 ms
I0606 18:58:13.302415    3690 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I0606 18:58:13.302454    3690 cached_discovery.go:119] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://11.22.33.44/api?timeout=32s": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
I0606 18:58:13.302495    3690 helpers.go:264] Connection error: Get https://11.22.33.44/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

any ideas? the workflow runs from a github hosted runner.

Comment: Has this ever worked? How are you authenticating to Google Cloud? Google's repo includes an [example](https://github.com/google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials#usage) that's functionally simillar to yours but uses Workload Identity Federation.